# Deploy Docker Image on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I am trying to deploy a ECS cluster for browserless. However running into some issue which I cant solve.

I will try to run you through what I did in the set up.

Went into ECS, create cluster, chose custom image, image path is  docker.io/browserless/chrome:latest for https://hub.docker.com/r/browserless/chrome/

Added port 80 and 8080 to port mapping.

Left everything on default/empty.

Ran the set up and everything is green and running after a while.

Trying to hit the public ip with no success (White Screen)

I check cloud watch I see this error

```
       /bin/sh: 1: cannot create 
      /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html: Directory nonexistent
```

Not sure how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around it for a while, I fixed the issue.

As the docker container is running on port 3000, I needed to add 3000 to the security group and hit the public ip with port 3000.

Comment: This is correct, you can also add a mapping from `80:3000` if you want to keep 80 as the port.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into some permission issue inside the container where it tries to create the index.html but fails due to insufficient permissions, you might try doing a CHMOD 755 over the directory , the other way to debug would be to run the docker locally and see if you end up with same issue, then you can add the CHMOD (if thats the issue) to your dockerfile to build the new image. Hope this gives you some direction

Comment: Ran docker locally works without any issues. Not sure how to edit the docker file to include the premission changes as I am pulling the image off docker hub in the ECS settings

Comment: Is the docker image build by u ? or you are using a 3rd party ?

Comment: Not by me. I have linked it on top. It's the browserless package

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason for this error could be the default command in container definitions, create a new task definition and in container definition settings, navigate to Environment Section and check the command, if there is any default command in the field, remove/update it.